# "Java concurrency in practice" - cached thread-safe number factorizer (Listing 2.8)

Tags: java, thread-safety, clone, local-variables

In the following code (copied from [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) Chapter 2, section 2.5, Listing 2.8):

```
@ThreadSafe
public class CachedFactorizer implements Servlet {
    @GuardedBy("this") private BigInteger lastNumber;
    @GuardedBy("this") private BigInteger[] lastFactors;
    @GuardedBy("this") private long hits;
    @GuardedBy("this") private long cacheHits;

    public synchronized long getHits() { return hits; }

    public synchronized double getCacheHitRatio() {
        return (double) cacheHits / (double) hits;
    }

    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) {
        BigInteger i = extractFromRequest(req);
        BigInteger[] factors = null;
        synchronized (this) {
            ++hits;
            if (i.equals(lastNumber)) {
                ++cacheHits;
                factors = lastFactors.clone(); // questionable line here
            }
        }
        if (factors == null) {
            factors = factor(i);
            synchronized (this) {
                lastNumber = i;
                lastFactors = factors.clone(); // and here
            }
        }
        encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);
    }
}
```

why the `factors`, `lastFactors` arrays are cloned? Can't it be simply written as `factors = lastFactors;` and `lastFactors = factors;`? Just because the `factors` is a local variable and it is then passed to `encodeIntoResponse`, which can modify it?

Hope the question is clear. Thanks.

Comment: Did you get an answer for the question after all these years?

Answer (score 3):

This is called defensive copying. Arrays are objects as any other, so

```
 factors = lastFactors
```

would assing a reference of lastFactos to factors and vice versa. So anyone can overwrite your state outside your control. As an example:

```
private void filterAndRemove(BigInteger[] arr);
private void encodeIntoResponse(..., BigInteger[] factors) {
   filterAndRemove(factors);
}
```

With our theoretical assignment filterAndRemove would also affect the original lastFactorials.

Answer (score 0):

Answer guessed from basics : You need to clone if you are planning to modify the Object, and you don't want to modify orginal object, in your case `factors = lastFactors.clone();` is done because you donnot want `lastFactors` to be modified instead you clone it and send it to `encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);` which may contain code to modify it.

Comment: Thank you. Correct me if I'm wrong, but there is no code that modifies the array held in `lastFactor` or `factor`. So no concurrent modifications of the array held in `lastFactors` can take place. Synchronization is needed to make assignments to `lastNumber`,`lastFactors` atomic, but not to prevent the concurrent modifications of `lastFactors`. So the question is open (to me).

Answer (score 0):

The only reason to clone arrays is to block (concurrent in this case) modification of the array elements. However, that doesn't look possible in this case assuming no other methods modify the array referenced by `lastFactors` which makes sense given the example. The arrays stored in `factors` and `lastFactors` are all created and returned in a complete state by `factor`, and their references are assigned inside synchronized blocks which will cause them to be safely published.

Unless `encodeIntoResponse` modifies its `factors` argument's elements, it looks to me like the calls to `clone` are unnecessary.

Comment: Hmmm... after a more careful review of the code and after re-reading @khachik comments I think that the above answer by @david-harkness is the most correct: since `lastFactors` is safely published, and is not modified after its publication it looks that cloning it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that that section of the book could have been better explained by the author of the book.

It is true that, in order to implement thread safety properly, you have to synchronize both **read** and **write** operations using the same lock; in the code above, in order to minimize the amount of synchronization, the author decided to perform the `encodeIntoResponse(...)` without synchronization: since the `encodeIntoResponse(...)` method **reads** the content of the array referenced by `factors` then the author cloned it into a new array.

Note: while it is true that `factors` is a local variable, in general, it would still require to be cloned because the same array is read by synchronized and not synchronized code, which could happen if we pass the reference (without cloning) to `lastFactors` and `encodeIntoResponse(...)`.

However, as correctly pointed out by @khachik in the question and by @david-harkness in a response, in this specific case the `clone` calls are unnecessary because `lastFactors` is safely published, and it is not modified after its publication.

Answer (score 0):

If you change `factors = lastFactors.clone();` to `factors = lastFactors;`, both `factors` and `lastFactors` point to the same object, `factors` is **no longer** a local variable, it becomes a **shared mutable state**.

Imagine there are three requests, request A, B, C. The number sent by Request A and B is 10, but the number sent by request C is 20. Things can go wrong if the below execution order happens and you change `factors = lastFactors.clone();` to `factors = lastFactors;`.

1. servlet server receives request A, the entire `service` method is executed, now `lastNumber` is `10`, `lastFactors` is `[1, 2, 5, 10]`.
2. servlet server receives both request B and C, request B is handled at first, but after exiting the first `synchronized` block (**now for request B, `factors` is `[1, 2, 5, 10]`, which is correct**), request C is handled.
3. for request C, the entire `service` method is executed, it **change `lastFactors` from `[1, 2, 5, 10]` to `[1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20]`**, because both `factors` `lastFactors` point to the same object, `factors` is now `[1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20]` too. **The response of request B is supposed to be `[1, 2, 5, 10]`, but is `[1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20]` right now**.

Comment: in 3 when you do lastFactors = factors it'll only modify the lastFactor reference and not the factors reference in the other thread. They both were pointing to the same object and now lastFactors points to a new object