# How the example from Java Concurrency in practice is thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Below is an example from book **Java Concurrency in Practice(Listing 2.8)** of a thread safe class.

My question is how the below class is thread safe?

For example if two threads `Thread A` and `Thread B` enter into service method of CachedFactorizer. `Thread B` followed by `Thread A`. Now if `Thread A` is executing first synchronized block and `Thread B` obviously waits for the intrinsic lock of the object. And if `Thread B` makes it to the first synchronized block before the `Thread A` makes it to the second synchronized block, it will be viewing a stale value and potentially this condition is known as **Race Condition**.

So, is my understanding right here? Or am I lacking some basic understanding of concurrency?

```
@ThreadSafe
public class CachedFactorizer implements Servlet {

    @GuardedBy("this") private BigInteger lastNumber;

    @GuardedBy("this") private BigInteger[] lastFactors;

    @GuardedBy("this") private long hits;

    @GuardedBy("this") private long cacheHits;

    public synchronized long getHits() { return hits; }

    public synchronized double getCacheHitRatio() {

        return (double) cacheHits / (double) hits;

    }


    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) {

        BigInteger i = extractFromRequest(req);
        BigInteger[] factors = null;
        synchronized (this) {
            ++hits;
            if (i.equals(lastNumber)) {
                ++cacheHits;
                factors = lastFactors.clone();
            }
        }
        if (factors == null) {
            factors = factor(i);
            synchronized (this) {
                lastNumber = i;
                lastFactors = factors.clone();
            }
        }
        encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be specific about what stale variable you're concerned about.

Comment: All the state variables.hits, factors, lastfactors and cachehits.

Comment: You're not the first to question this example, although this one was about using `clone()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034370/java-concurrency-in-practice-cached-thread-safe-number-factorizer-listing-2

Answer (score 3):

This class is thread safe because all shared variables are accessed in sychronized blocks, and in such situation there is no data race:

> "When a program contains two conflicting accesses (§17.4.1) that are not ordered by a happens-before relationship, it is said to contain a data race.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html"

The question is if this behaviour is valid from business point of view, eg. if two threads meet after first synchronized blok, they can execute second block in different order.

Comment: Yes, if two threads meet after first synchronized block, they can execute second block in different order, which may results in different values for 'lastNumber' and 'lastFactors'. --- That's the point here.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing used from within the first block after its exited is factors, which was cloned(), so is unaffected by any other threads getting into the first or second blocks.

Answer (score 0):

what's the difference if  I remove both clone()? eg: factors = lastFactors.clone(); I think it still works.

```
public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) {

    BigInteger i = extractFromRequest(req);
    BigInteger[] factors = null;
    synchronized (this) {
        ++hits;
        if (i.equals(lastNumber)) {
            ++cacheHits;
            factors = lastFactors; //not cloned
        }
    }
    if (factors == null) {
        factors = factor(i);
        synchronized (this) {
            lastNumber = i;
            lastFactors = factors;//not cloned
        }
    }
    encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);
}
```

Comment: 1.lastFactores only changed to Another array object.  not modify the content of the array object.  so no need to clone  2.  first synchronized  is  atomic operation of reading two share variables, second synchronized is  atomic operation of writing two varaibles.

Answer (score 0):

> it will be viewing a stale value and potentially this condition is known as Race Condition.

I guess what you meant by this, say thread A and thread B have `i` equal to 5. Before thread A execute the second block and set the `lastNumber` and `lastFactor`, thread B has already entered the first block, so it won't benefit from the already calculated cached value from thread A.

It's not a race condition. By definition:

> A race condition occurs when the correctness of a computation depends on the relative timing or interleaving of multiple threads by the runtime; in other words, when getting the right answer relies on lucky timing.

A program is considered correct if it doesn't violate the invariant. The invariant for this particular method, as explained by the author, is:

> ...the product of the factors cached in lastFactors
> equal the value cached in lastNumber; our servlet is correct only if this invariant
> always holds.

Weather or not thread B will benefit from thread A, it still will get its correct factor at the end.